# upgrading from ubuntu 17.04 to 18.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, xubuntu

I currently have ubuntu 17.04(zesty). I want to upgrade it to 18.04(bionic), but when I tried `sudo do-release-upgrade` I saw something weird like below and is telling ("An upgrade from 'zesty' to 'bionic' is not supported with this tool.").

Need inputs to resolve and proceed upgrade. what tool it needed to upgrade from Zesty to bionic. I searched in google but didn't found any supporting solution.

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
[sudo] password for arunseege: 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                           
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,257 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,258 kB in 6s (45.2 kB/s)                                             
authenticate 'bionic.tar.gz' against 'bionic.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'bionic.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager

Can not upgrade 

An upgrade from 'zesty' to 'bionic' is not supported with this tool.
```

Comment: This answer will help as you'll need to use the old-releases mirror https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release . You'll need to move to 17.10 and then another `do-release-upgrade` to 18.04, if you edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` so that the line `Prompt=normal` appear in place of LTS then the process will step one release at a time. 17.10 is officially unsupported but I think the normal repositories are still up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only upgrade from one version to the next (ex. 17.04 to 17.10) or from LTS to LTS (ex. 16.04 to 18.04). 17.04 is not a LTS version.

Comment: Hi @soren how to upgrade from 17.04 to 17.10 .

Comment: @spa .. you can't ... 17.10 is EOL as of 19 July 2018. The easiest would be to back up your data and install 18.04.

Comment: but i am using dual boot system @soren.